# Was Emperor Norton I recognised by Kamehameha V?

Tags: united-states, diplomacy, hawaii, primary-source

Emperor Norton I "reigned" as Emperor of the United States from 1859 to his death in 1880 – though he was mostly ignored by the *de facto* government of the time. [Wikipedia makes the claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Emperor_Norton&diff=prev&oldid=985792203) that his widely-disputed imperial authority was *recognised* by Kamehameha V of the Kingdom of Hawaiʻi:

> Near the end of his reign Kamehameha would refuse to recognize the democratic U.S. government, instead opting to only recognize Norton as sole leader of the United States.

Wikipedia cites two sources for the paragraph. One is a short work *Emperor Norton & Hawaii* by David W. Forbes (which I don't have a copy of), and the other is [a New York Public Library webpage](https://wayback.archive-it.org/18689/20220313121533/https://www.nypl.org/blog/2012/07/17/emperor-united-states) that doesn't seem to make this claim.

Are there primary sources that attest to this recognition?

Comment: I've never heard of this guy, but obviously he didn't 'reign', he just called himself 'Emperor'.

Comment: A colorful local character about describes Norton. I vaguely recall a Smithsonian magazine piece on him decades ago.

Comment: I hope the first sentence is tongue-in cheek.  You can never tell anymore when someone says something ridiculous like that.

Comment: @Spencer I edited. Is that clearer?

Comment: It looks like everything leads back to the Forbes book.